# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp

Tags: java

```
shaliya@achala:~$ java -version

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:   -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

I want to know how fix that message:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:   -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
```

Comment: That message means that you have an environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` set to the value `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp`. If you want to permanently unset that variable, you'd have to find the script file where it is set and change it. Check e.g. `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @ByteCommander [above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020670/picked-up-java-options-dawt-usesystemaafontsettings-gasp#comment1657207_1020670), it is set by either one of those file, but it could also be in `{netbeans-installation-dir}/etc/netbeans.conf` under `netbeans_default_options`. You can just remove it to get rid of the message, but note that you might have blurry text in some swing applications.